# Using a 640 Pixel width Image for the NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to use a picture with resolution of 640x88 Pixel for the Navigation Bar, but because of the screen resolution of only 320 Pixel width, only the half of the picture is visible.

If i use an 320 Pixel width Picture its fuzzy.

Maybe someone can tell me how to change the application resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the image properly to tell the Framework which is the retina and non retina version:

- myImage.png - normal version
- myImage@2x.png - retina version

Load the image normally (without the @2x), the framework will choose the proper version by itself:

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar 
         setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] 
              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```